# XSLT if statement failing with multiple similar entries

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, xslt-2.0

I'm having trouble with an *if* condition in my code. If I have two sets of nodes with similar subtrees and put an *if not* condition in my code then it fails the entries.

Over here I'm trying to show entries that don't have an entry containing *"imp"* or *"Imp"*

This is a simplified version of my actual code, but I'm having trouble with this

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" media-type="application/xml" standalone="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='fe'][@V='true'] and not(GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='sc'][contains(@V, 'imp') or contains(@V, 'Imp')])">
      <menuSection>
        <header>
          <horizontalDivider alignment="center">
            <title>Some Stuff </title>
          </horizontalDivider>
        </header>
        <items>
      <xsl:for-each select="GSP/RES/R">
      <xsl:if test="GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='fe'][@V='true'] and not(GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='sc'][contains(@V, 'imp') or contains(@V, 'Imp')])">
        --some stuff
      </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
        </items>
      </menuSection>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is a simplified version of my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<GSP VER="3.2">
    <RES SN="1" EN="2">
        <R N="1">
            <MT N="fe" V="true"/>
            <MT N="sc" V="low-pri"/>
        </R>
        <R N="2">
            <MT N="fe" V="true"/>
            <MT N="showcode" V="imp"/>
        </R>
    </RES>
</GSP>
```

if I remove the and condition on the first *if*

```
and not(GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='sc'][contains(@V, 'imp') or contains(@V, 'Imp')])
```

then the second if works correctly and shows me the entry for

```
<R N="1">
```

If I keep the first *if* as is then I don't get the *"Some Stuff"* header and the rest of it doesn't show either.

Comment: Your question is not clear. How is the result you get different from the one you expect?  --"*If I keep the first if as is then I don't get the "Some Stuff" header*" That's not what I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that when you write

```
test="GSP/RES/R/MT[X] and not(GSP/RES/R/MT[Y])"
```

you actually want both conditions to apply on the same MT node, whereas the way you have written it, the test will pass if there's one MT node where X is true, and no MT node where Y is true.

So I suspect you want

```
test="GSP/RES/R/MT[X and not(Y)]"
```

In your second xsl:if you have the context wrong. You have written

```
<xsl:for-each select="GSP/RES/R">
      <xsl:if test="GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='fe'][@V='true'] ...
```

but the context for the xsl:if is an R element, and an R element does not have a GSP child. What you intended here was probably

```
<xsl:for-each select="GSP/RES/R">
      <xsl:if test="MT[@N='fe'][@V='true'] ...
```

or more simply

```
<xsl:for-each select="GSP/RES/R[MT[@N='fe'][@V='true']] ...
```

Caveat: I haven't actually tried to work out the correct code for your requirements, I've just looked at where your code "smells wrong".

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this that you have tried

```
 <xsl:if test="GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='fe'][@V='true'] and not(GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='sc'][contains(@V, 'imp') or contains(@V, 'Imp')])">
```

Try out this

```
<xsl:if test="(GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='fe'][@V='true']) and (not(GSP/RES/R/MT[@N='sc'][contains(@V, 'imp') or contains(@V, 'Imp')]))">
```

I have included your first condition in first bracket and it worked at my end

Comment: That's exactly the same thing.